# Nullable object must have a value when using null conditional

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm having a InvalidOperationException

> "Nullable object must have a value"

when trying to set the value of a textform using a the null conditional operator when the `_socialSecurityBracket` is null/nothing. Nothing in MSDN tells me why it's making an error.

```
Class SocialSecurityBracket
    <Key>
    Public Property RowID As Integer?
    Public Property EmployerContributionAmount As Decimal
End Class

Public Sub Display()
    txtSocialSecurity.Text = _socialSecurityBracket?.EmployerContributionAmount
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be trying to assign a nullable decimal to a string property. The error isn't helpful beyond "something is wrong", but you'll need a type conversion in there. Since `EmployerContributionAmount` isn't itself nullable this should do:

```
txtSocialSecurity.Text = _socialSecurityBracket?.EmployerContributionAmount.ToString()
```

(If `_socialSecurityBracket` is null then null will be assigned, otherwise the decimal property will be converted to a string.)

Comment: Thanks it works. Is there a reason why mine doesn't? `txtSocialSecurity.Text = Nothing` works, so I'm not sure why `txtSocialSecurity.Text = _socialSecurityBracket?.Amount` doesn't when it's supposed to just return Nothing if the object is Nothing.

Comment: @Aaron Type of `_socialSecurityBracket?.Amount` is `decimal?`, but your assigning to a `string`.